# Can you force focus on a calling IE window on the close of a child IE window in Windows CE?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts, windows-ce

I have a struts application being used on handheld devices running Windows CE 4.2/5.0.

We needed the functionality of another app in this one, and the solution was to pop up a window to the other app (using window.open()), run the process, and then close the window to return to the original app.

Normally our apps always focus on a specific textbox after an action. When the new window closes, the original window does not become the active window, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to activate the window and focus on the textbox.

Is there a way to control which window becomes active when it closes and to trigger a focus event on the required field?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT: In case anyone comes across this question, it turns out accessing *window.opener* is not available in Windows CE unless the OEM specially included it in their version of the OS. See [this knowledgebase article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452009.aspx#wce50coninternetexplorer6supportinwindowsceanchor9) for more information.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Windows CE but with JavaScript you can use `window.opener` to refer to the parent window from within a popup. I wrote a little example to demonstrate. Hope it will be of help to you:

Save this as `parent.html` file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openPopup() {
        window.open("child.html", "", "dependent=yes,directories=no,height=400px,width=600px,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,title=yes,toolbar=no");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txtId" value="blah" />
<input type="button" name="btn" value="Open popup" onclick="openPopup();" />
</body>
</html>
```

and this as `child.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToParent() {
        window.opener.focus();
        window.opener.document.getElementById("txtId").focus();
        window.close();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
Push the button to close this window and focus on the parent's textbox<br />
<input type="button" name="btn2" value="Close popup" onclick="goToParent();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Your popup should close and focus should be gained by the calling page, even if it is in the background or there is some other windows on top.